# Inner dot product with these two vectors: anything special?

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, orthogonality

For example, I have two vectors, $\vec{x}=(x_1, x_2)^T$ and $\vec{y}=(y_1, y_2)^T$. If these two vectors are orthogonal, i.e., $x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2=0$, then do these two vectors have any interesting geometric properties:
$(cos\frac{x_1}{2} cos \frac{x_2}{2}, cos \frac{x_1}{2} sin\frac{x_2}{2}, sin \frac{x_1}{2} cos\frac{x_2}{2}, sin \frac{x_1}{2} sin\frac{x_2}{2})^T$ and $(cos\frac{y_1}{2} cos \frac{y_2}{2}, cos \frac{y_1}{2} sin\frac{y_2}{2}, sin \frac{y_1}{2} cos\frac{y_2}{2}, sin \frac{y_1}{2} sin\frac{y_2}{2})^T$ ?

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you consider interesting?

Comment: I'm not sure what orthogonality (particularly orthogonality in $\Bbb{R}^2$) has to do with this pair of vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$. They won't necessarily be orthogonal. What are you looking for here?

Comment: Oh thanks guys! Interesting properties might be: do their angles have a limited range? For sure that they won't necessarily be orthogonal. Or, if we carry out some (linear or nonlinear) transformations to these $\mathbb{R}^4$ vectors, will they then be orthogonal?